# Convert target coordinate space

Tags: actionscript-3, coordinates

How do I convert a point that is inside my MovieClip to coordinates on the stage (main timeline)?

Comment: use localtoglobal() function for this purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually localToGlobal is your friend in this battle.

```
var point:Point = myMovie.localToGlobal(new Point(10, 10));
```

If your movie is a child of another one:

```
var point:Point = myMovieParent.myMovie.localToGlobal(new Point(10, 10));
```

etc.

for more info see the [reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#localToGlobal%28%29).

Answer (score 2):

The command you want is localToGlobal. That command is used by creating a Point, passing the point to that method of the MovieClip, and then getting the converted point that's returned. Here's the page in the documentation:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#localToGlobal%28%29

Comment: [Is it okay to answer a stackoverflow question with a link?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13369/is-it-okay-to-answer-a-stackoverflow-question-with-a-link)

Answer (score 0):

You want to use localToGlobal :

```
var globalPoint:Point = clipParent.MyClip.localToGlobal(new Point(0,0));
```

here's the livedocs reference :[localToGlobal livedocs reference](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#localToGlobal%28%29)

Not sure why anemgyenge used 10,10 as that would return Point(20,20) if your movieclip was at 10,10 locally.